ESC POS protocol how to print NV image in Page Mode
I usually work with ESC POS in Standard mode and I use FS q / FS p to store NV images and print them.
Now I have to use the Page mode but I would like to print an image stored in NV memory like I did with ESC q.
In the manual if FS p command I found:
in Page mode, the NV bit image is only stored in the print buffer and is not printed.

Then I tried ESC FF to print buffer data,but it doesn't work.
Does somebody know how to print a NV image in Page Mode?

FS p / FS q are obsoleted commands, so it is better not to use them.
Currently, the commands to handle NV images are sequences starting with GS ( L / GS 8 L.
Obsolete Commands
However, depending on the vendor and model of the printer you are using, it may not be possible to use it, so please contact your vendor or reseller for accurate information.
Alternatively, the situation where printing is not possible may be due to some of the conditions written in the [Notes] of this article.
FS p [obsolete command]

As you ask in your question, you will print the page mode buffer with the ESC FF (or just FF) command.
The page mode buffer is entirely a graphics data buffer, so any text or image data written to it will be printed.
If nothing is printed and the paper just feeds, or if only text is printed, one of the precautions written in the [Notes] of the
FS p article mentioned above may apply to you.
If the paper doesn't even feed, the page mode setting may be incorrect.

If you can capture or redirect the data being sent to the printer and create a binary data file, you can use the Windows EscPos analysis tool(EscPosDecode.exe in this EscPosUtils repository) I created and released to check what commands and data are being sent.

I'm sure the printer supports NV Images because I can use them with FS p / q however I'm confused by this in Page mode, the NV bit image is only stored in the print buffer and is not printed. I could not understand how to print the image once is it in the buffer
